# Dont mix JSF and jQuery?

Tags: jquery

Now the only outstanding is the presentation layer. Want to build user interface for existing application.And as we all know presentation layer plays a critical role if its unsuccessful then rest all application is unsuccess. Choosing a presentation layer plays an important role.

Which is the best one to use for presentation layer? I thought of using jQuery after all filtering the Prototype,mootools, YUI, GWT and Dojo...however how does JSF fit into this?

JSF also has widgets and jQuery also widgets, both support event driven...how does these are compared? what are the advantages and disadvantages?

Struts 1.2/Spring we might use for business layer

and Hibernate for dataaccess layer.

Answer (score 1):

JSF is a component-based model for Java web UIs.  It's either JSF or Struts for the web tier, not both.  JSF compiles and runs on the server side.

jQuery, YUI, and their ilk are client side JavaScript frameworks.  jQuery is for DOM manipulation, but it also has UI component plug-ins.  I'd recommend sticking with one JavaScript framework throughout.

Spring is your glue code.  It can weld the web UI to the service tier without any issues.  You can use JSF, Struts, Spring MVC, or Wicket as you see fit.

Hibernate can be your persistence implementation.  So can Spring JDBC.  You'll use interfaces, so it'll be a matter of plugging the appropriate implementation into it.

You don't talk about the service tier at all.  If you expose your Spring services as web services, you can let any UI make service calls as needed.  This makes for a nice, decoupled, reusable API.

Comment: Thank you for quick response. so among JSf,Struts or Spring which is the recommended one. 

It might sound silly, so i have one more query. I did so much google search their i see JSF can be used for Rich UI etc. so same query again jQuery also provide widgets and components and JSF also so though JSF is component based model does that it can also the serve both the web tier and view/presentation layer?

and jQuery just for javascript validations?

Comment: For web MVC?  I'd recommend Spring.  I'm not a JSF fan at all.  I find it to be too heavyweight.  "Web tier" and "view/presentation tier" are synonyms in my opinion.  Write JSPs with jQuery in them and let Spring weld them together.  jQuery is more than just JavaScript validations.  You manipulate the DOM on the client side and perform AJAX calls with it.